# convergence in probability to a constant

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I have a sequence of random variables $X_n$ defined on $\Omega =[0,1]$ by $X_n(\omega)=\omega n$. Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

Does $X_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability?

I know that if $X_n$ converges in probability to a constant then $ \lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n-c|\gt\epsilon) = 0$

I am confused on the next step for proving or disproving this.

Thank you

Comment: First, note that convergence in probability suppose you have a probability on your space, and depends on that probability. What is the probability $\mathbb{P}$ ? The lebesgue measure ?

Comment: Yes the lebesgue measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : if you want to show that $X_n$ doesn't converge in probability to $0$, all you have to do is make sure that $\mathbf{P}(|X_n|>\epsilon)$ does not goes to zero. But 
$$\mathbf{P}(|X_n|> \epsilon) = \mathbf{P}(\omega : |\omega n| > \epsilon ) = \mathbf{P}(\omega : \omega > \epsilon / n)$$ which can be computed : if $\mathbf{P}$ is the Lebesgue measure, then
$$\mathbf{P}(\omega : \omega > \epsilon / n) = 1- \frac{\epsilon}{n} $$

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you. Do you mind elaborating a bit on the steps you took to arrive at last statment LHS=RHS wise, sorry I am a bit rusty.

Comment: It's the basic property of the Lebesgue measure : if $a<b$ , then $\mathbf{P}([a,b]) = b-a$. Here, $a = \epsilon/n$ and $b=1$ !

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask further questions on this site if you want details. Also, if the answer helped you, do not hesitate to upvote it or accept it as an answer : it might help other people !

Comment: ok. $X_n(\omega)=\omega n$ I don't quite understand what you did with $\omega n$ in your answer.

Comment: I've added the detail.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. So for example if $X_n(\omega)$ would be defined as $\omega^n$ could I write something like this: $\mathbf{P}(\omega : \ln\omega^n \gt \ln\epsilon)$ and then solve further. I am not sure how to handle well the absoulte value function, this is why I am asking.

Comment: Here, the absolute value is not a problem : your space being $[0,1]$, every $\omega$ is positive ! Also, what you wrote with the $X_n(\omega) = \omega^n$ is perfectly correct... and now your $X_n$ is converging to $0$ in probability :)

Comment: One last question: What is the last step in showing that this $\mathbf{P}(\omega : \ln\omega^n \gt \ln\epsilon)$ converges to $0$. I am having trouble rearranging with $\ln$.

Comment: You could use the properties of the $\ln$. But in fact there are easier ways : just elevate both sides to the power $\frac{1}{n}$. Then $\mathbf{P}(\omega^n > \epsilon) = \mathbf{P}(\omega > \epsilon^{\frac{1}{n}}) = 1 -  \epsilon^{\frac{1}{n}}$. As $n \to \infty$, you have $1/n \to 0$ and $\epsilon^{\frac{1}{n}} \to 1$, so the overall thing goes to zero.